# Compiling S-Transform python wrappers on Mac OS X 64 bit

Tags: python, compilation, 64-bit, wrapper

I am trying to compile a the s-transform python wrappers from [here](http://kurage.nimh.nih.gov/meglab/Meg/Stockwell) on my Mac (Mountain Lion, gcc45 installed from Macports, Python installed via Enthought 64-bit).

I am a user in science rather than a compiler expert and while it worked out-of-the-box on my Linux machine (just changed `int` to `npy_intp` and `PyArray_FromDims` to `PyArray_SimpleNew`), I don't really know how to get there on my Macbook...

So I build this Makefile:

```
PYINCDIR = /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/include/python2.7
NUMPYDIR = /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy CFLAGS = -O3 -I$(PYINCDIR) -I$(NUMPYDIR) -fPIC

all: sinemodule.so stmodule.so

sinemodule.so: sinemodule.o     $(CC) -shared -o $@ sinemodule.o

stmodule.so: stmodule.o st.o    $(CC) -shared -o $@ stmodule.o st.o
-lfftw3
```

And trying to "make", I get:

```
cc -shared -o sinemodule.so sinemodule.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_PyArg_ParseTuple", referenced from:
  _sine_taper_wrap in sinemodule.o
"_PyCObject_AsVoidPtr", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyCObject_Type", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyErr_Format", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyErr_Print", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyErr_SetString", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyExc_AttributeError", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyExc_ImportError", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyExc_RuntimeError", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyImport_ImportModule", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
"_Py_InitModule4_64", referenced from:
  _initsine in sinemodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sinemodule.so] Error 1
```

Maybe this is a very basic thing but to be honest I don't even know where to start reading to fix it...

Cheers for your help!

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue? I'm also trying to solve the same exact problem but did not found an answer

Answer (score 0):

I just found this abandoned post and wanted to share my solution.

First of all, as you did, you need to find the python and numpy include dirs of your python distribution.

In my case using Anaconda 1.9.1 this was

```
PYINCDIR = /Users/dengemann/anaconda/include/python2.7/include
NUMPYDIR = /Users/dengemann/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/
```

Second, you must not directly invoke the Makefile but make sure the setup.py in the top level directory is correct.

In my case 'darwin' was not explicitly supported, so I've added it.

```
# linux first
if sys.platform in ['linux2', 'darwin']:
    include_dirs = [os.path.join(NUMPYDIR, r'include/numpy')]
    libraries=['fftw3']
    library_dirs=[] # assume we use default locations
```

After these modifications running `python setup.py install` did the job and outputs look as expected.
HTH,
Denis